# Cannot print a text with Gosu in Ruby (crash)

Tags: ruby, crash, drawtext, libgosu

I'm trying to learn some basics of Gosu. I can display images but when i try with text the application crashed. Here's a simple code i'm trying to run.

```
<!-- language: rb -->
require 'gosu'

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
  def initialize(width=320, height=240, fullscreen=false)
    super
    self.caption = 'Hello'
    @message = Gosu::Image.from_text(self, "My text to print",Gosu.default_font_name,100)
  end

  def draw
    @message.draw(10, 10, 0)
  end
end

window = GameWindow.new
window.show
```

My system:

-Windows xp sp3

-ruby 1.93 448

-gosu 0.10.4

[###  cmd report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTFC0.png)

[###  cmd report 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O46v.png)

Comment: This may be a platform specific issue. I'd suggest reinstall `gosu` gem, as sometimes minor library version changes may result in segfaults. Or try more recent Ruby version if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As suggested i attempted to update ruby and to reinstall gosu. Sadly ruby versions over 2.0.0p647 doesn't work on xp. Anyway when i tried to reinstall gosu gem ruby gave some errors from converting some .so and .dll from ASCII-8Bit to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to everyone who have this problem on xp just install a previous version of gosu, with 0.9.2 works well.

Use: gem install gosu -v"0.9.2"

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

gosu 0.10.4

ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Running on ubuntu

[image: window]